# Multiprocessing with IMAP connection

Tags: python

I want to do a Python Script who get all emails in a BoxMail using IMAPClient and Multiprocessing, and I would like to know what is the best way to do that.

Because I don't really know what to uses, and how to think it.

If someone has an idea, let me know !

Comment: Please share a working code and let us know where are you stuck exactly.
The question is vague.

Comment: I didn't start anything, that's why I am asking you, how will you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps -

1) Try imapclient example in this documentation - https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/

2) In order to parallelize fetching message, you need to partition your e-mails so that each thread fetches different e-mail. One of the criteria could be date field.

3) Write a method using example code in documentation and parameterize search criteria (server.search).

4) Call above method in the multiprocessing code. Example for multiprocessing can be found at - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

5) You can also check "SEARCH commands" section in the RFC http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html to select your partitioning criteria if date is not suitable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i will check that :)